# How to correctly specify the type of an object of classes

Tags: typescript

I am instantiating an object of classes as part of my context.

```
 dataSources: (): Datasources => ({
      portalConfigAPI: new PortalConfigAPI()
    }),
```

I have setup the following type

```
export type Datasources = {
  portalConfigAPI: typeof PortalConfigAPI 
}
```

but get the following error

```
Property 'prototype' is missing in type 'PortalConfigAPI' but required in type 'typeof PortalConfigAPI'.ts(2741)
```

I dont understand the error, since the prototype will be set with the new instantiation of the class. What is the correct typescript for a function returning an object of classes?

Comment: `typeof PortalConfigAPI` -> `PortalConfigAPI`

Comment: You're confusing the class constructor (the static side) with class instances (the instance side); `typeof PortalConfigAPI` means "the type of the value named `PortalConfigAPI`... which is a constructor"; if you want the type of an instance you need just `PortalConfigAPI`.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Thankyou